# Sublime text 3 Popup windows & plugin execution

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm trying to build a plugin for Sublime Text 3 currently I have two questions I tried reaching the community over on Freenode/IRC but noone seems to be around and documentation on web is pretty scarce.

In any case at the moment my plugin works as intended however for it to work I have to open up the Console and type in `window.run_command("command")` is it possible to substitute this with a short cut command like `CTRL + MB2` without having to modify the users Key bind json config file on plugin install.

Second problem is that at the moment when my code executes it has to output into console window does ST3 API allow creating new windows within ST3 for instance a Dialog box populated with text data or a new sidebar.

The ST3 Unofficial docs have some very trivial information but nothing that goes past that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You will need to create a key binding file for your plugin. Though some authors choose to provide the command, then let the user define the bindings in their key binding files as to not override existing behavior. Take a look at `Default (<platform>).sublime-keymap` files for an example of what to do. The key binding files are merged together, so it'll have to be defined somewhere, whether by the user or within your plugin.
2. Take alook at `window#create_output_panel`

Comment: Is there a way to set the key binding in python as default but allow it to be overridden by key binding config file.

Comment: The merge behavior is Default,  then all packages alphabetically, then User.  So the user can override an existing binding,  but yours will still be there.  Well,  they can also modify package file if they want to remove it completely.